# Using R functions lapply and read.sql.csv

Tags: sql, r, csv, lapply

I am trying to open multiple csv files using a list such as the below;

```
filenames <- list.files("temp", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
```

I have found examples that use lapply and read.csv to open all the files in the temp directory, but I know appriori what data i need to extract from the file, so to save time reading i want to use the SQL extension of this;

```
somefile = read.csv.sql("temp/somefile.csv", sql="select * from file ",eol="\n")
```

However i am having trouble combining these two pieces of functionality into a single command such that i can read all the files in a directory applying the same sql query.

Has anybody had success doing this?

Comment: Do you want the files to be different dataframes or all merged into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of dataframes from each file (assuming your working directory contains the .csv files):

```
files <- list.files(".", pattern="*.csv")
df.list <- sapply(filenames, read.csv.sql,sql="select * from file ",eol="\n",simplify=F)
```

Or if you want them all combined:

```
df <- ldply(filenames, read.csv.sql,sql="select * from file ",eol="\n")
```