# How to merge multiple excel files

Tags: r, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have multiple Excel files, each with two columns. One being the same and the other being different for different files.

How can I merge all the files by their common column and save them as a new file?

**Note:**

I don't wish to combine them one under the other (using `rbind`). Instead, I want to `merge` them based on the commun column.

**For R:**

I have filenames in the following format.

```
percent- 15  knt 03_01__00_51.csv
percent- 20  knt 03_01__00_54.csv
percent- 25  knt 03_01__00_57.csv
```

Due to the file names format I can't write a script to read each file individually. I don't know how to write a loop that iterates over just 15 ,20 .... and leaves the end part somehow.

Comment: "don't want to read as data frames" seems like a silly restriction

Comment: That could be the last option. I am first looking if I can do it through excel.

Comment: Well, you could read them as a `list` of data.frames, merge them, and write them back to your folder. (If you don't want to use R, you should probably remove the R tag from your question .. )

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Check now the edit.

Comment: After your edit, is it safe to say you could just read all the `.csv` files in a folder?

Comment: I am unaware of how one can accomplish that. How do to name the dataframes then. Or do they get stored in a list?

Comment: Can someone refer to some code available.

Comment: You can do `filelist <- list.files(pattern = "^percent.*\\.csv$"); files <- lapply(filelist, read.csv, header=TRUE)` to read them all into a list

Comment: Similar to @docendodiscimus comment, check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134327/using-r-functions-lapply-and-read-sql-csv)

Comment: @akrun, they would not need it if those were the _only_ files in that directory.

Comment: All those files could be in that folder (which is how I understood your comment) but that doesn't mean that there are no other files in the folder.

Comment: @akrun, I'm well aware of that but thanks for the info.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia  If the pattern is as shown in the edit, something like  `list.files(pattern='percent- +\\d+ +knt \\d{2}_\\d{2}__\\d{2}_\\d{2}.csv')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do something like:

```
# if those are the only files in the folder, you don't even need a pattern
filelist <- list.files(pattern = "^percent.*\\.csv$")    # read all file names according to pattern
files <- lapply(filelist, read.csv, header=TRUE)         # read all files in filelist
files <- lapply(files, function(x) x[-1])                # remove first column of each file
DF = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "CommonColumn", all=T), files)   # merge all files
x <- sub("^(percent- )(\\d+)(\\s.*)$", "\\2", filelist)  # get the file name numbers 
names(DF[-1]) <- paste(names(DF[-1]), x, sep = "-")      # add file name numbers to column names in DF
write.csv(DF, "myfile.csv")                              # write data to new file
```

The `Reduce()` part is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list-simultaneously).

Comment: Works great. There is one problem though. Each file has three columns- Serial No. , Common Column , Different Colunm. Using the above code the Serial No. also gets copied from each file.

Comment: Is there anyway. If I can select two common columns or select which different column to taken from each file. Or any other way you suggest to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I wish to include serial no column and it is the first column. Can you please can make a edit in the original answer. It would better to understand that way.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use serial no column as a second common column? Your descriptions/comments are not very clear

Comment: Sorry. I don't want use serial no as a column. So the output would-<Common Column> <Different Column For File 1> <Different Column For File 2>..... . Here <Common Column> is the second column and <Different Column> is the third one in each file and <Serial Number> the first.

Comment: Thanks! Great. Could it possible to name the different columns by filenames as well? For example, consider the different column name is avgTime, so the output file should contain <Common Column><avgTime 15><avgTime 20><avgTime 25>...